# @GetMapping("/home") and @GetMapping("/folders/{id}") redirecting the same jsp/js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, rest, model-view-controller

I would like that @GetMapping("/home") and @GetMapping("/folders/{id}") redirect to the same home.jsp page/view, where I use jquery and ajax to createcontent. Unfrotunately when I call @GetMapping("/folders/{id}") in my Controller .js file is not working in my .jsp (the view doesn't recognize .js file and doesn't use jquery to build html page), but for @GetMapping("/home") everything works. Anyone knows why?

HomeController.java

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
private final FolderService folderService;

@Autowired
public HomeController(FolderService folderService) {
    this.folderService = folderService;
}

**@GetMapping("/home")
public String home(
) {
    return "home";
}

@GetMapping("/folders/{id}")
public String foldersId(
) {
    return "home";**
}
```

}

home.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>BOOKMARKS APP</title>

    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--JS files-->
    **<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Errors in console:

[image]

File structure:

[image]

Comment: Did you check your consoles for errors ? If the content you expect isnt there, its usually not loaded at all or loaded with errors.

Comment: @Lapskaus, yes there are errors (I posted screenshots) and it looks like sth wrong is in my file structure.

Comment: Either that, or the way you call the script points in the wong direction.

Comment: Solved. The resource path to JS in JSP should be: `<script src="/js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`